# Insert and update database with php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to insert and update  customer data by clicking on insert and update button using functions but when I click on insert or update button no data is inserted or updated whats the problem with my code??

```
<form action="Customer.php" method="post">

<div>

<form>

Phone No <input type="number"  placeholder="Search"  name="phoneno" />

First Name <input type="text" name="FirstName" />

Last Name<input type="text" name="LastName" />

Phone No<input type="number" name="CustomerPhoneNo" />

Address<input type="text" name="Address" />

Customer ID<input type="number" name="CustomerID" />

<input type="Submit"  value="Add Customer"  style="font-size:20px"  onClick="insert()"> 

<input type="Submit"  value="Update Customer"  style="font-size:20px" onClick="update()"> 

 </form>

 </div>


"Customer.php" 

<?php

$dbhost="127.0.0.1";
$dbname="root";
$dbuser="info";
$dbpsd="";

$link = mysqli_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpsd", "$dbname");


if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$phoneno = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['phoneno']);
$FirstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['FirstName']);
$LastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['LastName']);
 $CustomerPhoneNo = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['CustomerPhoneNo']);
 $Address=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Address']);
 $CustomerID = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['CustomerID']);


 function insert(){

     $sql = "INSERT INTO clientinfo(phoneno, FirstName, LastName,CustomerPhoneNo,Address,CustomerID) VALUES ('$phoneno', '$FirstName', '$LastName','$CustomerPhoneNo','$Address','$CustomerID')";
echo "<span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";

  if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

 }

 function update(){


 $sql="UPDATE clientinfo SET FirstName='$FirstName', LastName='$LastName',Address='$Address',CustomerID='$CustomerID WHERE phoneno='$phoneno' ";



if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($link);
}
 }
 close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: you can't use onclick tag to determine of requested page PHP function .

Comment: You have typo's within your code you have `two form tags`, `two submit button` and also post your js code too if you have

Comment: You're mixing the languages. That isn't going to work.

Comment: First of all the function name in `onClick="`" should a javascript function. Since you have not created any javascript function of that name it does nothing. If you want to make in php remove `onClick="`" and your functions and use `isset()`

Comment: Next thing is do not use nested <form>. try to avoid it to greater extent. also use name for your submit button to differentiate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use onclick tag to determine of requested page PHP function .
a easy way to do it . replace below codes at the customer.php file.

Replace :

```
function insert()
```

with :

```
if($_POST['Submit'] == 'Add Customer')
```

and replace :

```
function update()
```

with :

```
if($_POST['Submit'] == 'Update Customer')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Delete the second  tag and put the first one in that place.

Other thing, is that you need to review the code.

Review this Tutorial
[PHP Tutorial](http://www.sattsoft.com/tutorials/contents/1/27/add-edit-and-delete-data-using-php-and-mysql-step-by-step-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling php function like js functions. They dont work like that. Define them like -

```
function insert($link, $post){

    $phoneno = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $post['phoneno']);
    $FirstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $post['FirstName']);
    $LastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $post['LastName']);
    $CustomerPhoneNo = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $post['CustomerPhoneNo']);
    $Address=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $post['Address']);
    $CustomerID = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $post['CustomerID']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO clientinfo(phoneno, FirstName, LastName,CustomerPhoneNo,Address,CustomerID) VALUES ('$phoneno', '$FirstName', '$LastName','$CustomerPhoneNo','$Address','$CustomerID')";
echo "<span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";

  if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
      echo "Records added successfully.";
  } else{
      echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
  }
}
```

And cal them like -

```
insert($link, $_POST); // if it is inserting
```